# JS plugin bundles : What is `!function(e){function t(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;`?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to build a plugin that implements buttons on a specified region of a site. (ex: under certain div id tag, always place buttons).

I saw a similar plugin to the one I intended, called Sourcegraph (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sourcegraph-for-github/dgjhfomjieaadpoljlnidmbgkdffpack?hl=en ), and I'm trying to understand one of the files there (/js/inject.bundle.js, background.bundle.js, etc).

From my shallow understanding, plugins should have the 'original js template' of the website that you intend on changing, and should also have the intended 'inject' template in which the new added changes will be implemented. As I understand that the bundles in this js folder are critical for pinpointing where the changes should be made, I'm stifled on 1. how to get this code for the intended site 2. what exactly this code means.

Help would be very appreciated. TIA!

Comment: @JaromandaX (forgive me for my shallow understanding in advance), I meant that I thought the js folder (in specified chrome extension example above) should have the basic structures of the website in which I'm trying to modify.

Comment: [Getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) is a good jumping off point when creating, erm, Chrome Extensions

Comment: No, an extensions "js folder" has no relevance to anything other than the extension itself